# Using Karabiner to remap COMMAND_R to Hash #

Tags: hash, keyboard, karabiner

I have created a remapping in my private.xml file as follows to try and get round the need to use a modifier key to enter a hash:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <item>
        <name>Command_R to Hash # (Alt+3)</name>    
        <identifier>private.Command_R_to_hash</identifier>
        <autogen>
            __KeyToKey__ 
            KeyCode::COMMAND_R, ModifierFlag::NONE, 
            KeyCode::KEY_3, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L
        </autogen>
    </item>
</root>
```

However, when I have reloaded the file, COMMAND_R continues to work as a normal COMMAND_R.

I am using a MacBook Pro running OS X 10.11.2 (El Capitan) with Karabiner version 10.15.0

Thanks for any help and a Merry Christmas to one and all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <autogen>
  __KeyOverlaidModifier__
  KeyCode::COMMAND_L,
  KeyCode::COMMAND_L,
  KeyCode::KEY_3, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L
</autogen>
```

with this mod when you holding down "command" it act as "command", when you tap "command" it produce "#"

doc reference here
[https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/xml.html.en#syntax-**KeyOverlaidModifier**](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/xml.html.en#syntax-__KeyOverlaidModifier__)

recommend reading
https://stevelosh.com/blog/2012/10/a-modern-space-cadet/#better-shifting

Comment: Hi, apologies for the late response, I missed the notification for this answer. I have just tried this and it works perfectly. The second link is not working now, but the first was also very helpful. Many thanks.